Power bi desktop table visual out of memory on a simple DAX
I have a data model with Customer, Product, Insurer dimensions, and the fact table is FactClaims.
Customer dimension has cId, cName, cCompany, cDOB, cAddress
This links to FactClaims on cId.
On the report I have a table visual having several columns (10) from the FactSales, Product, Insurer tables, and cCompany from the Customer table.
I have the following DAX measure added into this table visual:
Scenario Test =
var vCount = DISTINCTCOUNT(Customer['cName'])

return IF(vCount>1,"scenario x","scenario y")

Upon adding this measure into the table visual, I get the visual exceeded the resources error.
The number of rows in Fact table is 1M, and number of rows in each dimension table is around 8K each.
I tried filtering data (by date, and other filters) such that the table visual contains only 30 rows, even then if I add the above DAX measure to the table, I get the exceeded resources error.
What could be the issue?

Your measure Scenario Test is always returning a value which will result in all the rows being returned regardless of filters.
As a test update your measure to:
Scenario Test =
var vCount = DISTINCTCOUNT(Customer['cName'])
return IF(vCount>1,"scenario x", BLANK())

And hopefully the error will disappear.
You'll then need to update your measure to something like the following:
Scenario Test =
  var vCount = DISTINCTCOUNT(Customer['cName'])
  var fCount = COUNTROWS('YourFactTable')
  var result = IF(vCount > 1,"scenario x", "scenario y")

  return IF(fCount > 0, result)


On the table visual, alongside columns from various tables, I have cCompany from the Customer table. Therefore the filter context for the measure is effectively only cCompany right? Then what exactly is causing the out of resources issue.

When a measure always returns a value (like measure = 1), the visual will effectively return all combinations of the columns within the visual, regardless of filters, slicers, or relationships.

Ok. I now understand your point. If I want to read more about this behaviour (about the combination), what article do you recommend?

Can you point me to some article for this concept.
